# How to correct tikz '\draw' location by hand?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I want to make a brace to the right of two nodes but I don't want it to be attached to but I want some extra space. For the starting location my solution seems to work well but for some reason the ending position is not affected. What am I doing wrong and how should I do it?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (foo) [draw, minimum width=6 em]
                {Foo};
    \node (bar) [draw, minimum width=6 em, below=of foo]
                {Bar};
     \draw [thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=6pt}] (foo.north east) + (1ex,1ex) -- (bar.south east) + (1ex, -1ex) node(foobar) [midway, xshift=3em] {FooBar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use `([xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]bar.south east)`

Comment: You need `($(foo.north east)+(1ex,1ex)$)` and `($(south east)+(1ex,-1ex)$)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any shift or those calculations, rather you can simply add `raise=<length>` to the brace options.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.geometric, positioning, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (foo) [draw, minimum width=6 em]
                {Foo};
    \node (bar) [draw, minimum width=6 em, below=of foo]
                {Bar};
     \draw [thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=6pt, raise=5pt}] (foo.north east) -- (bar.south east) node(foobar) [midway, xshift=3em] {FooBar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does of course not do exactly the same since it only changes things in one dimension. However, in most of the cases that is probably what is wanted anyways... :)

Comment: @jonalv Yeah, I saw you wanted to increase the Y axis too. I was looking into it to find an easy solution, because although adding dimensions is not wrong, it's also tedious.